# Python - input from a user

Tags: python-3.x

I am planning to configure a switch using python script and the sample code is below.
Values like interface name , ip address are to be obtained from the user and I want my output to be list as shown below:

```
    int_device_configs = ['interface GigabitEthernet0/0^
    ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0','interface GigabitEthernet0/1^
    ip address 192.168.9.10 255.255.255.0,'interface Management0/0^
    ip address 10.197.104.233 255.255.255.224]
```

Is it possible to obtain the same set of values using input function ??

I am not able to obtain the interface and the ip address within the input function as below.

How to obtain multiple values within the input function:

```
    switch=[]
    i=0
    while 1:
     item=input(('interface %s ip address %s'))
     if item=='':
         break
    switch.append(item)
    print(switch)


    Expected from the interpreter:
    interface <value from the user>,ip address <value from the user>
    interface <value from the user>,ip address <value from the user>
    interface <value from the user>,ip address <value from the user>
```

...
...
until the user inputs nothing.

Comment: Call `input` twice per loop iteration

Comment: @Dan Can you please elaborate it for me in the form of a code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to calls to `input` in your loop:

```
interfaces=[]
addresses=[]
i=0
while 1:
    interface=input('Interface: ')
    if interface=='':
        break
    interfaces.append(f'interface {interface}')
    address=input('Address: ')
    addresses.append(f'ip address {address}')
print([item[0] + ', ' + item[1] for item in zip(interfaces, addresses)])
```

Comment: @SukanyaParam. Nothing to do with me. It wasn't taken back though, your question was downvoted by a different person from whomever upvoted.